# scp from a remote server - Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, ssh, scp

I am trying to copy a `tar` file from a remote server to the local machine. The command is

```
sshpass -p 'somepass' scp someuser@somedomain:/some/dir/some_file.tar.gz /local/dir
```

Syntactically, the command seems correct, however it yields:

```
scp: /some/dir/some_file.tar.gz: Permission denied
```

- `someuser` is not a `root` user, but I made him own `/some/dir` with `chown -R`
- `some_file.tar.gz` is set to read and write with `chmod`
- I looked up a dozen similar questions but of them resolved my issue.

What could be the issue here and how do I resolve it?

#### EDIT

Running `sshpass -p 'somepass' ssh someuser@somedomain ls -ld /some/dir/some_file.tar.gz` (as Jakuje suggested) gives me

```
ls: cannot access '/some/dir/some_file.tar.gz': Permission denied
```

The end folder (which is under `root` dir) with `some_file.tar.gz` has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- someuser root ... ... ... some_file.tar.gz
```

Comment: make sure the permissions are correct. Try `ssh someuser@somedomain ls -ld /some/dir/some_file.tar.gz` and post the output to the edited question.